# Should questions that are very country dependant have the country name in the title?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Tags are all good etc, but when I see a questions in a list, e.g.  “Related panel” often 90% of them are of no use to me as they are about other countries with very difference legal and tax systems.

Edit - It was suggested to me in the Mods chat that I add the feature-request tag.

The feature requested above is that if a question has a country tag, the related results contain that tag as well, more so if the tax tag appears too.

Comment: Keep in mind, meta traffic runs very light compared to main Money.SE site. A lack of response doesn't mean a lack of interest, it may take a few days to start to see activity.

Comment: I guess we need some one from SE to answer on the Related Questions are shown. My guess is some tags are matched. However more tax question will have country tag and tax tag. Thus there are common tags to the question and related questions shown. In money.se we need more weighting to some specific tags [country tag for example]. However there is no mechanism to distinguish a set of tags from other.

Comment: @Dheer - if a question has both a tax tag and a country tag, the related posts should have both those tags, right? Your high country tag weighting implies that. That seems the best simple way to solve Ian's concern, which I agree with.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer Yes, if we are tagging consistently. If we try and do a perfect match, in other set of case the related question may not result in anything. So I guess there is no simple answer and needs some analysis.

Comment: I'll bring this up in the mods chat. The related algorithm may be sitewide, and this tag's importance may be limited to just a few specific boards.

Answer (score 3):

Ian - I saw you left a comment at one of my answers from 2012. Before I answered, I checked the member's profile for location, and then offered a US-centric answer.

I don't know how the related post algorithm functions. I have my own issues with it, as I often click to find it sent me to a closed question. It's something that needs to be addressed there, and probably simpler to do so.

Trying to go back and change how questions are titled might impact the 'related' results, but a more direct approach might be better.

The other issue here, is that a question might be general as was [Should I dip into an emergency fund to cover expenses for a rental property or only use it to make emergency repairs, improvements, etc.?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/13396/should-i-dip-into-an-emergency-fund-to-cover-expenses-for-a-rental-property-or-o/13400?noredirect=1#comment81108_13400), although my answer, to your point, was US. And as I noted, it was more to address something many small landlords miss, but didn't actually answer his question.